# Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: Class constructor $b802fbb11c9bd2dc$export$2e2bcd8739ae039 cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am trying to use emoji-mart in my app but I keep getting this error
Here's my code

```
import data from '@emoji-mart/data'
import { Picker } from 'emoji-mart'

 {showEmojis && (
                
                <Picker 
                   data={data}
                   onEmojiSelect={addEmoji}
                   style={{
                    position:"absolute",
                    marginTop: "465px",
                    marginLeft: -40,
                    maxWidth: "320px",
                    borderRadius: "20px",
                  }}
                  theme="dark"
                  />
              )}
```

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnHlL.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have imported `Picker` from wrong location.

Official Docs: https://github.com/missive/emoji-mart#react

STEP 1:

```
npm install --save emoji-mart @emoji-mart/data @emoji-mart/react
```

STEP 2:

```
import data from '@emoji-mart/data'
import Picker from '@emoji-mart/react'
```

STEP 3:

```js
{showEmojis && (
                
                <Picker 
                   data={data}
                   onEmojiSelect={addEmoji}
                   style={{
                    position:"absolute",
                    marginTop: "465px",
                    marginLeft: -40,
                    maxWidth: "320px",
                    borderRadius: "20px",
                  }}
                  theme="dark"
                  />
              )}
```

Comment: His import is not wrong and it's not the problem here

Comment: I have the same problem. I know emoji-mart changed but I can't figure out what to do to make it work. I did the installations of the three packages here suggested. I tried both the imports (from emoji-mart and emoji-mart/react). I tried both ways. They're both failing. I try cancelling and restarting the server. One time it worked. Then nothing again.